# How to fix this infinite loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I am currently making a game where you dodge lasers.  I want the laser to move to a random y position on the screen.  Then it will fire the laser beam once the laser is at the desired random location.  And repeat this until the game is over; aka you hit the laser beam.

I don't know how to make it work without having problems with infinite loops since I am still pretty new to java and libgdx.

Changed the tags from javascript to java. Sorry.

WHAT YOU SHOULD DO: After a lot of confusion I remade the class.  I combined fire() and move() into one method, and made it be called from my Screens render method (render is called every frame).

```
package com.JrodManU.LaserJumper;

import java.util.Random;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;

public class Laser {
    public Sprite image;
    public Rectangle bounds;
    public LaserBeam laserBeam;
    public boolean on;
    public long timer;
    public Random random;
    public int targetY;
    public float speed;
    public boolean moving;

    public Laser(int x) {
        moving = false;
        on = false;
        random = new Random();
        image = Assets.laser;
        bounds = new Rectangle(x, random.nextInt(892) + 32, 32, 16);
        laserBeam = new LaserBeam();
        move();
    }

    public void fire() {
        laserBeam.bounds.y = bounds.y - 5;
        on = true;
        timer = TimeUtils.millis();
        while(on) {
            if(timer + 1000l < TimeUtils.millis()) {
                on = false;
            }
        }
        move();
    }

    public void move() {
        targetY = random.nextInt(892) + 32;
        speed = (targetY - bounds.y) / 100;
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            bounds.y += speed;
        }
        fire();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your infinite loop, and why is this tagged Javascript? I only see Java.

Comment: Java and Javascript are 2 very different languages.

Comment: This is java not JavaScript.

Comment: When the object is created in my Screen class it starts move(), move() starts fire() when it is complete. When fire() is complete it starts move(). And I will change the tags, as I said I am new so I get the two confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laser calls `move()` which calls `fire()` and `fire()` calls `move()`.

The **loop** is between `fire()` and `move()`.

You need to prevent this somehow(using a `return;` inside fire\move with a condition will do the work).

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the infinite loop where move() calls on fire and then fire() calls back on move().

To do fix the issue you need to have a condition to break this call loop. For example when the laser hits the player in the fire() function. Here is some pseudocode to give you an idea:

```
 public void fire() {

    if (playerHit)
        gameOver();
    else
        move();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with the `1000l` in your condition? why is there an `l` in there? you could also change your loop to

```
while (true) {
  if (...) { break; }
}
```

instead of making an extra boolean to keep track of the whole thing?

Comment: There is an `l` because it is a `long`, although capital `L` should always be used (`1000L`) to prevent confusion between `1000l` and `10001`.